# No Connectivity on Windows 7 WSHELPER.DLL not found

Tags: windows-7, internet, dns, connection, malware

I have a **Windows 7** laptop, which i am fixing for a friend. There is no connectivity at all. I have tried several interfaces - Ethernet, WLAN, Mac OSX internet sharing over ethernet.

Internet Explorer diagnostics reveal that **The DNS server is not responding**, I am using OpenDNS for name resolution. I have read about a potential Windows 7 WinSock problem, supposedly resolved by issuing

**netsh winsock reset catalog** and
**netsh int ip reset reset.log hit**

However for each of these commands, I receive an error: **The helper DLL WSHELPER.DLL could not be loaded**.

I have tried several ways to register the DLL but each time it reports it cannot be found, even though it exists in System32, System64 and SysWOW64. I have tried:

**regsvr32 wshelper.dll** and
**netsh add helper wshelper.dll**

How can I restore connectivity?

Thanks

Comment: Are the devices detected and do they have the needed drivers?  What were you fixing originally?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I'm having a similar issue.